# Mobile Detect And URL Variables

Tags: php

I cannot seem to figure out why this is not working.
My site has a php script that detects mobile devices and loads the appropriate style sheet.
This works fine, but I've decided to add a url variable to the code for testing purposes.

If I'm on my tablet or pc and i want to view the phone portion of the site i'd simply go to http://example.com?device=phone but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks ahead of time.

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/mobiledetect.php');
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
if(isset($_GET["device"])) {
 $device = $_GET["device"];
}
if($detect->isTablet() || $device == "tablet") {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/style.php">'."\r\n";
}
else if ($detect->isMobile() || $device == "phone") {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/m.style.php">'."\r\n";
}
else {
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/style.php">'."\r\n";
}
```

Comment: You should be using `Media Queries` for responsive design with a single style sheet, what you are doing is device detection based on the `User Agent` and is not a best practice.

Comment: Not a best practice, but i do use it for more than just styles. This is just a basic code. For example on another site i may have php variables that vary from mobile to desktop.